# How does finding average work in this scenario?

Tags: probability

Consider this scenario you draw a card from a deck and after drawing you put the card back into the deck. The odds pulling a red card is 0.7%.

On average, how many draws will it take to get a red card?

I thought its pretty obvious and you $$0.007 x = 1, x = 142.85$$

On average it would take $143$ draws. Is this right?

My friend said you have a 75% chance to get red card in 200 draws..? where is he getting that number

Comment: For me the scenario is not clear but obviously $0.007\%\neq 0.007$

Comment: meant 0.7% the decimal version is 0.007. my bad

Comment: The $75\%$ chance thing doesn't have much to do with averages. Is your question about the average or about the  $75\%$ chance?

Comment: On average, how many draws will it take to get a red card? According to my calculation I got it would take on average 143 draws but my friend said im wrong since you have a 75% chance with 200 draws (idk where he got that from).

Comment: @mol Yes, you're right, that $\mathbb E(X)=\frac1{p}$, where $X$ is a geometric distributed random variable.

Comment: 1 draw is 0.7% chance to get a red card. 100 draws is 70% chance to get a red card on average. but then wouldnt 200 draws be 140%. it cant be higher than 100% right? im confused by that

Comment: @mol 100 draws do not give you 70% chance. Consider the same experiment but with 50% chance: would 2 draws give you 100% chance?

Comment: @mol I suggest, that you learn more about the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). This will give you a better understanding.

Comment: This will be easier if you use a letter, say p, for the probability of drawing a red card, and use the letter q = 1-p for the probability of not drawing a red card. Now find the probability, say f(N), that the first red card occurs on the Nth draw. Finally, you want to find the sum of the infinite series 1*f(1) + 2*f(2) + ... + N*f(N) + ..., and that will be the expected (or average) number of draws that you are looking for. Express that infinite sum as a function of p and then plug in the specific value of p that you want.